# How do you know where macports installs python packages to?

Tags: macos, troubleshooting, osx-leopard, macports

I am running macports to install scipy and such on OS X leopard with python 2.7.  The install runs successfully, but running python and trying to import the packages I've installed, they're not found.

What I'm running is:

```
sudo python_select python27 
sudo port install py27-wxpython py27-numpy py27-matplotlib 
sudo port install py27-scipy py27-ipython
```

Opening up python in interactive mode (it is the correct version of python), I type 'import scipy' and get a module not found error.  What gives?  How can I find out where it is installing the packages to instead?

Comment: How do you start python - what bersion does it print at the start and what is the value of sys.path?

Answer (score 2):

MacPorts installs Python 2.7 packages at `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Check to make sure that this path is in `sys.path` in Python. SciPy would be installed in `scipy` under that directory. Also check `port contents py27-scipy` to ensure that the files are in the right place.

Comment: If that path is not in sys.path, how can I add it?

Comment: If you're running MacPorts Python located at `/opt/local/bin/python` then it should already be added for you. Are you sure you are running the right Python? Is `/opt/local/bin` in your `PATH`?

Answer (score 2):

```
port contents py27-scipy
```

compare this with the ouput of:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sys.path)
```

Comment: Thanks! Always wanted to know such command as port contents.